# Can we check other application activity in rooted android device?

Tags: android, root, sandbox

Due to the sandboxing, applications in devices are installed as making inaccessible from each another. But in case of rooted device, and providing all the permissions, whatever is required, can an application access other application's data, variables or foreground screen ?
In my case, I need to scan the certain activity by OCR, when it is foreground. I think, it needs to OS level of permission, but can this level of permission be accessed and used in rooted device ?

Comment: Did you yourself tried anything so far?

Comment: Really people ? -1 for this question ? @AADTechnical, I have tried using recentTaskinfo to get the activity, but couldnt manage anything to do for accessing data.

Comment: What information are you trying to access? For app "data", you can access any app's data under the `/data/app.apk` with some extraction/processing. For live variables and interacting with app's activities you will need to create an Xposed module. You can capture an app's foreground as a png with terminal's `screencap` command. With that, point us in the right direction.